# How do you convert events from AS2 to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on AS3. how do you convert this AS2 code to AS3?

```
on(press) {
    zaman = setInterval(cogalt,1);
}

on(release) {
    clearInterval(zaman);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a name of your button and use the following code:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.utils.clearTimeout;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// ...

var zaman:uint;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    zaman = setTimeout(cogalt, 1);
});
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    clearTimeout(zaman);
});
```

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'as', Frame 1, Line 5 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before tripledot.  

now i get this message....

Comment: @user2695395 do you really think the ellipsis is supposed to be taken literally, rather than as an indicator of an elided piece of code?

Comment: @JanDvorak; he did say 'use the following code'. @user2695395; please actually notice the differences and learn from it rather than copying it and having the same problem with different events tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to point out that the imports should be at the top of your file. I just commented the three dots.

Comment: @JonoRR; thank you for your advice. i will keep that in mind. 
@Krasimir; thank you so much, but now, i get this message. "Line 7 1151: A conflict exists with definition cogalt in namespace internal"

Comment: That's because you already define that function. Just remove it. I just updated the answer again.

Comment: @Krasimir; Thank you so much for your reply. It was very very helpful! ;) All of you thank you.